# trying to display other fields from specific access database recordset in asp

Tags: asp-classic

I'm new to ASP and have a form that lets users choose a division code from a dropdown box that is populated from an access database. Once they have selected the division, I'd like to be able to collect other fields (name, address, city, state, zip) from that same recordset and pass those fields to another asp page. I'm able to write the selected code to the database, but can't figure out how to collect the other fields from that specific line in the table. My code is

```
<%

Set objconn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objconn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("data/jobdata.mdb")
objconn.Open

Set objRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM EagleLocations "
objRs.Open strSQL, objconn
Response.Write "<select name=DCode><option value='' selected></option>"
Do While Not objRS.EOF 

Response.Write "<option value='" & objrs("DCode") &"'>"& objRs("DCity") &"</option>"
objRS.MoveNext
Loop
Response.Write "</select>"
objRs.Close
objconn.Close

%>
```

How do I get the page to also get the DName, DAddress1, DAddress2, DCity, DState, and DZIP fields from the selected DCode?

This is my receiving page code where I'm trying to get the data I collected from the form on the previous page to write to a different database:

```
<%
Dim objconn,strSQL,objRS

Set objconn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objconn.open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("data/jobdata.mdb")

Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL= "SELECT * FROM EagleLocations where Dcode =" & Request.Form("DCode")
objRs.Open strSQL, objconn

    DIM strjobstart, strpm, strdcode, strdname, strcustname, strjobsite, strjobsubject, strworkmancompcode
    strjobstart = Request.Form("jobstart")
    strpmcode = Request.Form("pmcode")
    strdcode = Request.Form("dcode")
    strdname = Request.Form("dname")
    strcustname = Request.Form("listcustname")
    strjobsite = Request.Form("listjobsite")
    strjobsubject = Request.Form("jobsubject")
    strworkmancompcode = Request.Form("workmancompcode")

    IF strjobstart <> "" AND strpmcode <> "" AND strdcode <> "" AND strcustname <> "" AND strjobsite <> "" AND strjobsubject <> "" AND strworkmancompcode <> "" THEN

    ' Process the form as you like here
    ' For example enter form to your database or send it via email

jobstart = request.form("jobstart")
pmcode = request.form("pmcode")
dcode = request.form("dcode")
dname = request.form("dname")
custname = request.form("listcustname")
jobsite = request.form("listjobsite")
jobsubject = request.form("jobsubject")
workmancompcode = request.form("workmancompcode")

Set Cnn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Cnn.open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("data/jobcode.mdb")

strSql = "INSERT INTO JobCodeTemp (jobstart,pmcode,dcode,dname,custname,jobsite,jobsubject,workmancompcode) values( '" & jobstart & "' , '" & pmcode & "' , '" & dcode & "' , '" & dname & "' , '" & custname & "' , '" & jobsite & "' , '" & jobsubject & "' , '" & workmancompcode & "' )"

Cnn.Execute(strSql)
Cnn.Close
Set Cnn = Nothing


    'Redirect to the index.asp page
Response.Redirect "display.asp"
```

csarafin

Comment: Can you please clarify some things. 1. do you need to select those fields on this page or do you only need them on the next page. 2. If you need them on the current page: Is JQuery or javascript ok to use to complete this task.

Comment: Couldn't you just create another recordset on the receiving page, with a query like `strSQL= "SELECT * FROM EagleLocations where Dcode =" & Request.Form("DCode")`

Comment: I need the information from these additional fields on the next page only because I am writing information from that page to a different databse but don't know anything about JQuery or javascript either.

Comment: If I change my process, I create the recordset on the receiving page and I got that to work. This will most likely mean I need to add another step to the overall process for the user.

Comment: This is my receiving page code: